# Pull in Individual File/Directories from External Repositories of Different Structure while Retaining Git History

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github, diff

A project I'm working with will be pulling in individual files from many remote repositories. It is vital that every file pulled in retain its full commit history from its original repository when its pulled in to the new one so that its commit history can be referenced in the future.

I can't seem to find the correct method/workflow for doing this. I am storing the remote repositories locally while I am pulling/working with the files. The repositories I'm pulling from also have completely different directory structures so I am also moving the file to a new path whenever I pull one in.

It would be ideal if there were some sort of GUI that would allow side by side file movement between repositories with history but its not that big an issue to cd to the current repo path and pull the file into it if needed with the remote path. I looked at the git archive command but it would not pull in history, is there a way to use the checkout command for this?

The files I'm pulling in have very detailed commit histories that comment exactly why certain things are changed which is why I need the full individual file history retained(I don't need commit history from any commits that don't affect the file being pulled in). Some of the repositories I'm pulling from were originally svn repos that I converted to git but that's probably not causing any issues as the repo history appears to be present.

Sometimes I am merging files from external repositories and it would be ideal if I could retain some sort of history for both although I'm not sure if that's possible, a lot of the time I'm overwriting files and I would like to have the history of the new file instead of the old one, or maybe at least mark where the merge came from, that's not as important as I can mark origin in the commit though.

Would it be easier to use Mercurial for this?

Comment: unrelated to the question itself, in the future, I'd recommend not having you question be an 18 line block of text, because it deters people from reading the whole post. Try breaking it up into sensible paragraphs with an obvious question stated.

Comment: Hopefully its easier to read now.

Comment: Do the repos you wish to pull in have other files and directories in them, or does each repo just contain the file you want to pull in? If there *are* other files and directories in the repos, were they ever committed alongside the files you care about? If so, you'll need to use some fancy `git filter-branch` work to chop the other files out of the commits and reduce the commit set to only the ones that contain the files you care about, and maybe some `git rebase -i` work to fix up the commit messages so they don't contain info about other files and directories.

Comment: There are many other files and directories that I don't want to pull in from the repos. Most of the time the files are committed alongside files that I don't want. Guess its pretty tricky to do. I've been experimenting with mercurial since it may be more suitable for this project style anyways.